# Timeout on a GET Webrequest

Tags: c#, webrequest, httpwebresponse

I have a WebRequest as this however I retrieve large files with this and gives timeouts with large files, however I am not able to extent the timeout to unlimited or at least 10 minutes, somebody know how to do this?

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
httpWebRequest.CookieContainer = user.cookies;
httpWebRequest.Host = uri.Host; 
httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
httpWebRequest.Accept = user.post_headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == 8).Value;
httpWebRequest.UserAgent = user.post_headers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == 4).Value;
httpWebRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
httpWebRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;
httpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
httpWebRequest.KeepAlive = true;
HttpWebResponse response_posts = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse())
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the `Timeout` Property on the `HttpWebRequest` object

[HttpWebRequest.Timeout Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

#
EDIT 1:

It actually appears that the Timeout property may have an effect on the initial connection and does not dictate the timeout for receiving information in GetResponse()

"This is the time for the server to respond to a request, not the amount of time to wait for the server to respond and send down all of the data"

Although this is conflicting to what MSDN states;

"The Timeout applies to the entire request and response, not individually to the GetRequestStream and GetResponse method calls."

So, you could also try setting the `ReadWriteTimeout` property.

[HttpWebRequest.ReadWriteTimeout Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Yes I already underfinded this if you send on  minutes it just waits  minutes to execute )))) I will try the ReadWriteTimeOut

Answer (score 0):

This is another solution

```
request.Headers["timeout"] = "300"; // in seconds
```